# Auto newlining ostream

Tags: c++, std, ostream

Sorry in advance for the bad title, not sure what to call what I'm trying to do.

Some background, if you don't care to read, skip to the next paragraph. I have a unit test class where I call assert with some condition and if it fails I output some string that was passed in. I have found that it is quite annoying to build a string to send to this if for instance I want to say `"Failed on index: " + i`. My idea is to return a `std::ostream` instead of taking a `std::string`. If the assert fails I return `std::cerr`, if the assert passes then I return a `std::stringstream`. I imagine I could do all of this just fine. I'd have to store a `std::stringstream` in my unit test class so I can return a reference.

What I would like to do is instead of returning a standard `std::ostream` return an extended `std::ostream` that outputs `std::endl` when it's done so I don't have to remember it for each assert. In particular the idea is the following:

```
UnitTest("My test");
ut.assert(false) << "Hello world";
ut.assert(1 == 0) << "On the next line";
```

The idea being that on destruction this new class would output the endline and that it would be destructed as soon as it was no longer used (i.e. no more << operators). So far this is what I have (I've removed some of the code in assert, and it's actually inside a class, but this is sufficient to show what's going on):

```
class newline_ostream : public std::ostream
{   
    public:
    newline_ostream(std::ostream& other) : std::ostream(other.rdbuf()){}
    ~newline_ostream() { (*this) << std::endl; }
};

newline_ostream& assert(bool condition, std::string error)
{
    if(!condition)
    {
        return newline_ostream(std::cerr);
    }

    return newline_ostream(std::stringstream());
}
```

When I try this method I get some stuff basically telling me that returning an object I just created is wrong because it's not an lvalue. When I try changing it to not return a reference it complains that there's no copy constructor (presumably this is because I'm extending `std::ostream` and it doesn't have a copy constructor).

What I'm looking for is some method that causes the compiler to create a temporary newline_ostream that `assert()` will write it's result into that will die as soon as it's no longer used (i.e. no more << operators). Is this possible and if so how?

Answer (score 2):

Copying `std::cerr` isn't possible (the copy constructor of `std::basic_ostream` is deleted). Therefore, creating a derived class that implements a copy constructor is not really an option.

I'd suggest you create your `newline_ostream` as a class that *contains a reference to* (rather than is derived from) `std::ostream`:

```
#include <iostream>

class newline_ostream
{
  std::ostream &_strm;
public:

  explicit newline_ostream(std::ostream &strm)
    :_strm(strm)
  {}

  /* In the destructor, we submit a final 'endl'
     before we die, as desired. */
  virtual ~newline_ostream() {
    _strm << std::endl;
  }

  template <typename T>
  newline_ostream &operator<<(const T& t) {
    _strm << t;
    return *this;
  }
};

int main()
{
  newline_ostream s(std::cerr);
  s << "This is a number " << 3 << '\n';

  /* Here we make a copy (using the default copy
     constructor of the new class), just to show
     that it works. */
  newline_ostream s2(s);
  s2 << "This is another number: " << 12;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your saying I couldn't make a copy constructor got me thinking, and I came up with my answer. Would you mind commenting on whether there's anything wrong with it (like not being portable)?

Answer (score 2):

May be an heresy, but instead to derive a stream to produce another stream type, a more generalized way can be to define a manipulator:

```
// compile with g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -pedantic

#include <iostream>

class sassert
{
public:
    sassert(bool b) :ps(), good(b) 
    {}

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, sassert&& a)
    { a.ps = &s; if(a.good) s.setstate(s.failbit); return s; }

    ~sassert()
    { 
        if(good && ps)  ps->clear(); 
        if(!good && ps) *ps << std::endl; 
    }

    //move semantics allow sassert to be a result of a calculation
    sassert(sassert&& s) :ps(s.ps), good(s.good) { s.ps=nullptr; }
    sassert& operator=(sassert s){ ps=s.ps; good=s.good; s.ps=0; return *this; }
private:
    std::ostream* ps;
    bool good;
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << sassert(false) << "this is a failed assertion";
    std::cout << sassert(true) << "this is a good assertion";
    std::cout << sassert(false) << "this is another failed assertion";
    std::cout << sassert(true) << "this is another good assertion";
    return 0;
}
```

Will run producing

```
this is a failed assertion
this is another failed assertion
```

Comment: If it's an heresy, it's definitely a very smart one. +1.

Comment: @jogojapan: like all smart ideas though, they run afoul of established practices. There is no reason that the "streamed" objects could not be checking the state of the stream too and for example throw an exception when it's failed.

Comment: @MatthieuM. I doubt that _all_ smart ideas do that... but anyway. What are the established practices regarding the use of the failbit? Is throwing an exception when the failbit (not the badbit) is set considered appropriate?

Comment: @jogojapan: I honestly don't know, but I can imagine some people may have used it so. I did not mean established practices in a canonical way, I meant "practices that exist today". It is not so much as testing the badbit than just testing whether the stream is ready to accept input or not.

Comment: @MatthieuM.: according to the standard, the failbit is set when a stream cannot read or write something because of its nature (is is typical when you cannot read a number because the input supply text).

Always according to the standard, when the failbit is set **all operations are possible** an no I/O is made. About the "establilished practices" ... simply I don't know what you are talking about...

Comment: ... I cannot take care of every possible use: if their  behavior does not conform to the standard, it is their problem, not mine. An throwing an exception from a streamed object, do in fact disallow every possible control of the stream state from the caller, thus making "*all operation not always possible*".

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia When does the destructor get called (i.e. what is the lifetime)?

Comment: @CrazyCasta: after the expression where the temporary object belongs has been fully evaluated (let's say ... at the ';')

Comment: @EmilioGaravaglia I don't understand how it's kept alive until the ';'. It looks like it just gets consumed by cout and dies immediately. Can you explain how that is not the case? (Or how the ';' magically kills the object).

Comment: @CarzyCasta: as per the standard, temporary objects are destroyed in reverse creation order when a "sequence point" is reached. A "sequence point", always per the standard, is (among others) the *end* of an expression evaluation. Now, consider that the << operator is left-associative, put all together and you find that `sassert` is created before the first `<<` is called and destroyed at the ";". It's not "magic": it's how C++ works. You simply felt it wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It really depend on the specifics of what you want to achieve.

If you have never heard of [*Type Tunneling*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_Tunnel_pattern), for example, it might be a good moment to read about it. There is a way to use shims to do some crazy things...

Otherwise, here is a simple version:

```
class AssertMessage {
public:
    AssertMessage(): _out(nullptr) {}
    AssertMessage(std::ostream& out): _out(&out) {}

    AssertMessage(AssertMessage&& other): _out(other._out) { other._out = nullptr; }

    AssertMessage& operator=(AssertMessage&& other) {
        if (_out) { _out << "\n"; }
        _out = other._out;
        other._out = nullptr;
        return *this;
    }

    ~AssertMessage() { if (_out) { _out << "\n"; } }

    template <typename T>
    AssertMessage& operator<<(T const& t) {
        if (_out) { *_out << t; }
    }

private:
    std::ostream* _out;
}; // class AssertMessage
```

Note how by embedding a pointer we do not need a global "null" object ? That's the main difference between pointers and references. Also the note the use of the move constructor/move assignment operator to avoid outputting **2** newlines or more.

You can then write the `assert` method:

```
AssertMessage UnitTest::assert(bool i) {
    return i ? AssertMessage() : AssertMessage(std::cerr);
}
```

However.... I would seriously consider using a macro, if I were you, because you get extra perks:

```
#define UT_ASSERT(Cond_) \
    assert(Cond_, #Cond_, __func__, __FILE__, __LINE__)

AssertMessage assert(bool test,
                     char const* condition,
                     char const* func,
                     char const* file,
                     int line)
{
    if (test) { return AssertMessage(); }

    return AssertMessage(std::cerr <<
        "Failed assert at " << file << "#" << line <<
        " in " << func << ": '" << condition << "', ");
}
```

And then you will get something like:

```
Failed assert at project/test.cpp#45 in foo: 'x != 85', <your message>
```

It is invaluable, in large test suites, to have the file name and line number (at least).

Finally, a macro gets you even more: if you call a function in your message such as `ut.assert(x) << x.foo();`, then `x.foo()` need be evaluated completely even when the message will not be printed; this is quite wasteful. However with a macro:

```
#define UT_ASSERT(Cond_, Message_) \
    while (!(Cond_)) { std::cerr << .... << Message_ << '\n'; break; }
```

then if condition evaluates to `true` the body of `while` is not executed at all.

Comment: Why would I want to use a while. Seems like that would just jam it up in an infinite loop.

Comment: @CrazyCasta: Exact, I missed the `break`. The problem is generic with macros. Macros with several statements need be embedded into a block, otherwise they don't play well with `if` or `for`: `if (..) MACRO` becomes `if (...) stmt1; stmt2; stmt3;` which is parsed as `if (...) { stmt1; } stmt2; stmt3;` by the compiler. So generally you wrap them up in a `do { ... } while(0)` block; which is a single instruction-block syntax wise. Here, since we need a `if`, we can use a `while` block instead, with a `break` at the end (we need to avoid the *dangling-else* issue).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the preprocessor for this:

```
#define U_ASSERT(ut, cond, stream) \
    do { ut.assert(cond) << stream << std::endl; } while (0)

U_ASSERT(ut, 1 == 0, "The result is " << (1 == 0));
```

However, this and the method you already use (with the modifications by jogojapan) are basically the only alternatives. This is because even if you start working with buffers you can't tell when one output operation is done and the next starts, so you don't know when to put in the newline.

Comment: Just fyi, I came up with a solution that works for me. Let me know if there's anything you see wrong with it though. (I'm assuming the user isn't going to store the newline_ostream).

Answer (score 0):

I found out a way that works for me (specifically I return a copy rather than a reference):

```
class newline_ostream : public std::ostream
{   
    public:
    newline_ostream(const std::ostream& other) : std::ostream(other.rdbuf()){}
    newline_ostream(const newline_ostream& other) : std::ostream(other.rdbuf()){}
    ~newline_ostream() { (*this) << std::endl; }
};

newline_ostream assert(bool condition, std::string error)
{
    if(!condition)
    {
        return newline_ostream(std::cerr);
    }

    return newline_ostream(nullStream); // nullStream defined elsewhere (in the class)
}
```

Usage:

```
ut.assert(ps.getFaces()[i] == expected[i], ss.str()) << "Test " << i;
```

Output:

```
Test 0
Test 1
Test 2
Test 3
Test 5
Test 7
Test 9
Test 10
```

Comment: You should elaborate on what you did (no longer returning a reference)

Comment: Copying the stream buffer is possible and basically a good idea, I think. As far as I can tell this should work when you create a `newline_ostream` from `std::cerr`. You would, however, get into trouble when you create one from the temporary `std::stringstream` in the original version of your `assert` function. Now you have the `nullStream`, which I suppose is a global object. I am a little concerned what happens if you reset that global string stream (e.g. by calling `nullStream.str("");`). This may invalidate the stream buffer pointer held by existing `newline_ostream` objects.

Comment: Admittedly, my original answer doesn't address that aspect at all. It only talks about how to make a copy constructor possible; so the question of how to ensure that the string stream (if one is used instead of `cerr`) lives on is a separate question.

Comment: The nullStream is a protected member of my UnitTest class. So as long as I don't clear the string (which is a good point since I was thinking of doing just that to reduce memory usage), I should be okay. The other possibility is that I might think about extending newline_ostream to provide a null_ostream class that would include a stringstream of its own.